# Can't validate self signed certificate - TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed

Tags: android, ssl

I am trying to establish secure communication with remote server, which is unfortunately self signed. 
I read official android docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html and it is written here, that when certification authority is not in android list, you need to accept server certificate by yourself. So I did it like this:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream mInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mCertificateBytes);
Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(mInputStream);

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate);
TrustManager[] customTrustManager = {new CustomTrustManager2(keyStore)};
kmf.init(keyStore, null);
KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

sslContext.init(keyManagers, customTrustManager, null);
```

and my CustomTrustManager2.java is like :

```
public class CustomTrustManager2 implements X509TrustManager {

private final X509TrustManager originalX509TrustManager;
private final KeyStore trustStore;


public CustomTrustManager2(KeyStore trustStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        KeyStoreException {
    this.trustStore = trustStore;

    TrustManagerFactory originalTrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    originalTrustManagerFactory.init(this.trustStore);

    TrustManager[] originalTrustManagers = originalTrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    originalX509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) originalTrustManagers[0];
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
    try {
        originalX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    } catch (CertificateException originalException) {
        originalException.printStackTrace();
        try {
            X509Certificate[] reorderedChain = reorderCertificateChain(chain);
            CertPathValidator validator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
            CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
            CertPath certPath = factory.generateCertPath(Arrays.asList(reorderedChain));
            PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(trustStore);
            params.setRevocationEnabled(false);
            validator.validate(certPath, params);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw originalException;
        }
    }

}
```

But it is NOT working, I am getting error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err? at om.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
W/System.err? at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
W/System.err? at com.test.sample.utils.http.CustomTrustManager2.checkServerTrusted(CustomTrustManager2.java:78)
W/System.err? at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(SourceFile:164)

W/System.err? at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/System.err? at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err? Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err? ... 31 more
I/System.out? First error end
I/System.out? second error start
W/System.err? java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.
W/System.err? at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:122)
W/System.err? at com.sec.android.security.pkix.SecCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(SecCertPathValidatorSpi.java:100)
W/System.err? at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:191)
W/System.err? at com.test.sample.utils.http.CustomTrustManager2.checkServerTrusted(CustomTrustManager2.java:90)
W/System.err? at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(SourceFile:164)
W/System.err? at com.google

W/System.err? at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err? Caused by: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.AnnotatedException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.
W/System.err? at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.findTrustAnchor(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:237)
W/System.err? at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:117)
W/System.err? ... 31 more
W/System.err? Caused by: java.security.SignatureException
W/System.err? at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.verifyOpenSSL(SourceFile:353)
W/System.err? at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.verify(SourceFile:384)
W/System.err? at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.verifyX509Certificate(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:1431)
W/System.err? at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.findTrustAnchor(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:224)
W/System.err? ... 32 more
```

Comment: So the server certificate is not only self-signed but invalid. Complain to the server admin.

Answer (score -2):

I think you'll have issues as long as it's a self signed certificate, there isn't a way for them to get a valid certificate signed by a third party? Because a self-signed certificate will always give you issues when there's a firewall between the two devices.

Comment: Firewalls have precisely nothing to do with it.